# Rails 6 ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I built a basic rails app only for contact form using - gem 'mail_form'. It works perfectly in the development environment. However, I deploy the app in Heroku and only got an error in the production environment.

config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer_default_url_options = { host: "https://myapp.herokuapp.com" }
  # Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'https://gmail.com'
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'gmail.com',
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV['GMAIL_EMAIL'],
    password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZNLB.png)

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set `GMAIL_EMAIL` and `GMAIL_PASSWORD` in your app environment?

Comment: Hi @eugen, Thanks for your response. I did have those in development and production. I store var value in .env file. Would you be more specific, which app environment do you talk about? :)

Comment: On `Heroku` you have to set the values of the configuration variables. Run `heroku config` and make sure those two variables are listed there. If they aren't, you have to set them manually with `heroku config:set VARIABLE_NAME VALUE`

Comment: @eugen They are. I'm still wondering why I got 500 server error and  ArgumentError (SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your configuration, but fact is on Heroku they have following information

Gmail have protections in place to avoid their service being used to deliver spam, however these are not published for security reasons. However we often see issues where customer applications attempt to use a Gmail account for email delivery which is subsequently blocked. So it mean there is some sort of block.

You are suggested to use email add-ons from [email add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons)